# Do we need a Routing Table to connect 2 Subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet

Im learning AWS and Im confused about connecting 2 Subnets. Do we need a Routing Table to connect 2 Subnets?

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes,

> A route table contains a set of rules, called routes, that are used to
>   determine where network traffic is directed.
>
> Each subnet in your VPC must be associated with a route table; the
>   table controls the routing for the subnet. A subnet can only be
>   associated with one route table at a time, but you can associate
>   multiple subnets with the same route table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html